# React: preventDefault() not preventing multiple onClick events being fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling

I'm using React and am trying to write a basic tab system. The tabs are a rectangle with an interior close-button, like so (with render method):

[image: tabs]

```
this.props.tabs.map(function(tab, index) {
    return (
      <a key={index} onClick={() => this.props.handleTabClick(index)}>
          <span className={"title"}>
            {tab.title}
          </span>
          <span className={"button"} onClick={(event) => {
              event.preventDefault();
              this.props.handleCloseTab(index);
          }}>
            <Glyphicon glyph="remove" className="glyph"/>
          </span>
      </a>
    );
}, this)
```

The Glyphicon is just an "X" icon I'm using for the button, and the handler functions handle things like highlighting the appropriate tab and removing tabs from the list.

#### However, when I click the "X" button to close the tab, the onClick functions for both the outer `<a>` tag and the inner `<span>` are called, and it both closes the tab and tries to navigate to it.

`event.preventDefault()` does not appear to be affecting this behavior. I tried using `event.stopPropagation()` instead, but it refreshes the page.

How can I ensure that only one event is fired?

Comment: You might consider to create two parallel buttons inside the tab instead of a button inside a button.

Comment: add onclick on parent and do nothing, or add `pointer-events: none` css on element